# Macro to check date range against criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, vlookup

I need VBA code to check each weekday date in a date range against a table in another sheet, if the corresponding value is >9% for any of the days, it should return a msg box

i.e, in the "Leave Request Template", the code should check each of the weekdays for the range given in B7 and B9, against the "Master" worksheet in "Leave Tracker Master" sheet, if the corresponding value for any one date in the "Total" column is >9%, it should return a msg box

I have written the below code for it, but i get a type mismatch error while running the code (The error in on the Vlookup line of code)

```
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim wsCheck As Worksheet
Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application
Dim EmailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim leaveDate As Date
Dim st As Date
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

  Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application
  Set EmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  Set wsCopy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
 
  If wsCopy.Range("C4") = "" Or wsCopy.Range("B7") = "" Or wsCopy.Range("B9") = "" Or wsCopy.Range("B13") = "" Then
     MsgBox "Please enter all required fields "
     Exit Sub
  Else
  Set wsCheck = Workbooks.Open("G:\Manager Folder\Test\Leave Tracker Master.xlsx").Worksheets("Master")
  st = wsCopy.Range("B7").Value
  Set myrange = wsCheck.Range("A:D")
  Do While st <= wsCopy.Range("B9").Value
    If (Application.VLookup(st, myrange, 4, False) > 0.09) Then
    MsgBox "Leave cannot be Applied"
    Exit Sub
    End If
    st = st + 1
  Loop
  
  
  Set wsDest = Workbooks.Open("G:\Manager Folder\Test\Leave Tracker Master.xlsx").Worksheets("Tracker")
  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
  leaveDate = wsCopy.Range("B7").Value
  
  Do While leaveDate <= wsCopy.Range("B9").Value
    If (leaveDate Mod 7) > 1 Then
      wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow) = wsCopy.Range("C4").Value
      wsDest.Range("B" & lDestLastRow) = wsCopy.Range("E4").Value
      wsDest.Range("C" & lDestLastRow) = wsCopy.Range("G4").Value
      wsDest.Range("D" & lDestLastRow) = wsCopy.Range("B1").Value
      wsDest.Range("E" & lDestLastRow) = leaveDate
      wsDest.Range("F" & lDestLastRow) = wsCopy.Range("B13").Value
      lDestLastRow = lDestLastRow + 1
    End If
    leaveDate = leaveDate + 1
  Loop
  ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
  End If
       
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(...)`

Comment: It gives the same error, i've even tried ```If (myrange(st, 4).Value >= 0.09) Then``` this runs the macro, but doesnt perform the check at all !!!

Comment: My guess would be that the error is because the VLookup call returns an error status that cannot be compared with the number `0.09`. Try assigning its value to a variable declared as variant : `Dim whatever As Variant`, then try to display the variable.

Comment: You are supplying far too much code. You have an error in 1 line. So, start with that line. Does it work on your Excel sheet, as a `=VLOOKUP(...)` function with the arguments you are trying to apply? You will get an error of `#N/A` if the date you are looking up (variable `st`) is not found in column `A` of the worksheet that you are looking up. That is one potential source of your Type Mismatch error. Another as @harrymc notes is if the value returned from the Vlookup is incompatible with your comparison operator (>=).

Comment: Thanks, for the inputs, they helped me understand, It was returning an error, I tried using datevalue and it seems to have fixed the issue!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the datevalue function solved the problem

```
 Do While st <= wsCopy.Range("B9").Value
         If (Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(st, myrange, 4, False) >= 0.09) Then
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).